# Font awesome icon inside of materialize input

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to put a font awesome icon inside the materialize text input, but to no luck. I dont mean regularly like they show on their website.

I mean like this:

[image]

Current Code:

```
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important;">
            <div class="input-field col s12" style="margin-top: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important;">
            <span style="right:8px;top:10px;" class="fas fa-user"></span>
            <input value="X (4)" id="tag" type="text" class="validate white-text" disabled">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12" style="margin-top: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important;">
            <span style="right:8px;top:10px;" class="fas fa-user"></span>
          <input value="X Coin" id="type" type="text" class="validate white-text" disabled">
            </div>
          </div>
```

As you can see on the image it's actually inside the materalize input since it's inside the inputs border-bottom.

This uses default materalize (my code).

How would i accomplish this? I've tried adding the font awesome besides inside of the input field div but it wont align besides it. Or inside it.

Thanks for reading.

Regards.

Comment: Did you tried with `<i class="fas fa-user"></i>` *or* like `<i class="fa fa-user"></i>` ?

Comment: Yes, same result. I want it inside the input like shown on the picture

Answer (score 1):

you just need change position :

```
 <div class="position-relative">
         <div class="input-field">
             <input  type="text" />
             <label for="datepicker2">Add</label>
         </div>
         <div class="position-absolute" style="top:5px;right:0;">
          <i class="material-icons">add</i>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the desired effect by using only [`css`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) properties to look-a-like structure.

```css
body {
  background-color: #4a647b;
}
input {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #d1cfd9;
  padding: 5px;
}
.input-field {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d1cfd9;
}
.fa {
  color: #d1cfd9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 200px">
  <div class="input-field col s12" style="margin-top: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important;">
    <span style="right:8px;top:10px;" class="fa fa-user"></span>
    <input value="X (4)" id="tag" type="text" class="validate white-text" disabled>
  </div>
            
  <div class="input-field col s12" style="margin-top: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important;">
    <span style="right:8px;top:10px;" class="fa fa-user"></span>
    <input value="X Coin" id="type" type="text" class="validate white-text" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: View on Codepen]

---

Also there is syntax error on your input element.

Change this :

```
<input value="X (4)" id="tag" type="text" class="validate white-text" disabled">
```

to :

```
<input value="X (4)" id="tag" type="text" class="validate white-text" disabled>
```

Comment: Anyway to integrate it into materalize? Materalize already has a border bottom!

Comment: I tried copying your code and applying it to mine and it turned out like this: https://imgur.com/a/Hkp4PLR

Comment: Try with removing `width: 200px` from the code *or* add `display: inline-block` css to input field.

Comment: Yea cause rn its above a bit, im trying to push it down but i cant due to the padding

Comment: Okay tried display: inline-block and removed with: 200px from row div, same result. I also tried adding margin top to the icon to push it down but i can't due to the padding of the input itself

Comment: Decrease the width of `input` field

Comment: Okay added border to the input-field class instead, and now its working but any idea how to decrease the space between the  input and the border line? Image: https://i.imgur.com/1XdoBUN.png

Comment: Try to decrease `padding-bottom` of `input` field.

Comment: Also, how would i make so the text above and under are aligned with eachother? So it doesn't look wonky..? https://imgur.com/a/yNKHPaH

Comment: Also padding-bottom is already forced to 0px using !imporant inline styling. Still the same.

Comment: Set definite `width` to icon `<span>` element. And for padding issue, you need to provide some demo link in order to get idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Width or margin?

Comment: No. Only `width`

Comment: Nvm, i set width to 20 for both span's and it still doesnt line up?

Comment: It seems, some kind of online code workaround needed to play for what's mess up. Sounds like Materialize css clashing with custom css. Try to provide minimal code in demo link (like codesandbox, jsfiddle or codepen)

Comment: Fixed it, now i'ts only he padding issue left dunno why its so high up/ border is so much more down

Comment: May be decreasing (minus) `margin-bottom` in `input` field can work. But this is not the correct way to do this.

Comment: Realized i didnt have margin-bottom on the input itself. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You most welcome @KlaessTurbolent :)